# Multiple joins in SQL on a WordPress site with references through postmeta

Tags: sql, wordpress

This one's going to be a bit of a challenge to describe. I have a very unusual case I need to write a query for in WordPress.

I have a post type, called `artists`, and another one, called `performances`. Artists have a meta value with the key `artist_id`.
Performances have the same meta key, referencing the artist. I realize this alternate subsystem of IDs is ridiculous, but it's the way things are for a bunch of other reasons, you'll have to trust me that they're sensible.

Performances have another meta key of `show_set_time` that contains a UNIX timestamp.

**I need to write a query that can get me all artists that have a performance after a certain date.**

Let me know if that's unclear. I completely recognize, again, that the ID keys are ridiculous, but there are other factors involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously untested, but I think it should work:

```
SELECT *

FROM (SELECT NULL) AS dummy

INNER JOIN
wp_posts AS artist
ON artist.post_type = `artist`

INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS meta_artist_id
 ON meta_artist_id.post_id = artist.ID
AND meta_artist_id.meta_key = 'artist_id'


INNER JOIN
wp_posts AS performance
ON artist.post_type = `performance`

INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS meta_performance_artist_id
 ON meta_performance_artist_id.post_id = performance.ID
AND meta_performance_artist_id.meta_key = 'artist_id'
AND meta_performance_artist_id.meta_value = meta_artist_id.meta_value

INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS meta_performance_date
 ON meta_performance_date.post_id = performance.ID
AND meta_performance_date.meta_key = 'show_set_time'

WHERE
meta_performance_date.meta_value > DATE('2012-12-21')
```

Comment: Of course you can remove the dummy table, but then you have to move one joined table's `ON` conditions into the `WHERE` block.

Comment: Thanks! I'm almost there - this is almost working, the only problem is it's returning a few dozen copies of each of the two artists that currently meet the query's requirements (testing this with three performances and three artists, one performance's set time set to '1' and the others much higher, and when I query with meta_performance_date.meta_value `> 1` I get two versus `> 0` I get all three). Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Hi, the above query lists all combinations of artists and performances. If you just `SELECT artist`, it will still combine them with the performances. If you want just the artist, try `SELECT DISTINCT artist.*` or something similar (you could use an approppriate `GROUP BY artist.ID` instead of `DISTINCT` if you want)

Comment: There we go, DISTINCT and some tweaks did it (this is actually part of a query builder, so the actual implementation is tricky). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. BTW, the query also could be rewritten using `EXISTS`/`IN`, so you can experiment with them too, if you wish :)